# Переписать важные сообщения простым языком

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, справка, стиль

Рекомендую вам посмотреть на сайт http://public-notice.ru/, где даются примеры разных объявлений, переписанные простым и в то же время мощным и убедительным языком.

У нас на сайте тоже есть тексты, которые можно было бы улучшить в этом направлении:

- Письма от модераторов (там вообще порой бывает треш и угар).
- Разделы справки про различные запреты — что такое «плохо» и как нельзя себя вести.
- Подробные сообщения при закрытии вопроса.

Предлагаю познакомиться, подумать и поделиться мыслями. К активным действиям пока не призываю — рано.

Comment: Там иллюстрации — огонь, но лицензии нет (т.е. закрытая), так что я написал автору. Разрешит — добавлю картинки.

Comment: "Время ожидания соединения истекло"

Comment: @alexolut время, ожидание, соединение и стекло. :)

Comment: Модератором делать нечего подробно расписывать?

Comment: Что за письма от модераторов? Как работает эта система?

Comment: @Alex78191 это один из самых эффективных методов работы модератора.

Comment: @Nikita если участник сильно нарушает правила или ему нужна адресная помощь, модератор может ему написать. У нас есть полтора десятка шаблонов таких писем и вот эти шаблоны можно улучшить.

Comment: А можно куда-нибудь выложить примеры плохо написанных текстов? (Например, в вопрос.) Или ссылки в transifex для _избранных_.

Comment: @VladD про текст о бане за оскорбления я отдельный вопрос создавал. Остальные наверняка можно. Они и в транзифексе есть.